# Grab the color of a pixel with Xcb instead of Xlib

Tags: c++, xlib, xcb

I use several window manager and if i understand correctly they use xlib. (awesome,openbox,fluxbox...)

I use the following code to detect the amount of "RED" in a pixel :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    XColor c;
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay((char *) NULL);
    int RED;
    int x=atoi(argv[1]);
    int y=atoi(argv[2]);
    XImage *image;
    image = XGetImage (d, RootWindow (d, DefaultScreen (d)), x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes, XYPixmap);
    c.pixel = XGetPixel (image, 0, 0);
    XFree (image);
    XQueryColor (d, DefaultColormap(d, DefaultScreen (d)), &c);
    RED=c.red/256;
    cout << RED;
}
```

But it always return 0 with my `i3-gaps` window manager. (works with others wm)

I guess it's because `i3` doesn't use `Xlib` but `Xcb` instead.

If so, how can i achieve the same thing with `Xcb` ? (Something backward compatible from Xlib syntax ?)

Comment: A window manager has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just replaced `#include <X11/Xlib.h>` by `#include <xcb/xcb.h>`.

Amazing...

Comment: This makes no sense. It has nothing to do with whether the window manager uses Xlib or XCB, nor does replacing the include work. That should just fail to compile with the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure C example, but it can also be used in C++. Note, I haven't done any error checking, but it should definitely be added for anything more than a demo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_image.h> 
#include <inttypes.h>

// https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic.html
#define AllPlanes   ((unsigned long)~0L)
#define XYPixmap    1

int main() {
    // Location of pixel to check
    int16_t x = 0, y = 0;
    
    // Open the connection to the X server. Use the DISPLAY environment variable
    int screen_idx;
    xcb_connection_t *conn = xcb_connect(NULL, &screen_idx);

    // Get the screen whose number is screen_idx
    const xcb_setup_t *setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);
    xcb_screen_iterator_t iter = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);  

    // We want the screen at index screen_idx of the iterator
    for (int i = 0; i < screen_idx; ++i)
        xcb_screen_next(&iter);
    xcb_screen_t *screen = iter.data;
    
    // Get pixel
    uint32_t pixel = xcb_image_get_pixel(xcb_image_get(conn, screen->root, x, y, 1, 1, AllPlanes, XYPixmap), 0, 0);
    printf("%d", pixel);
    return 0;
}
```